# How to compose generators with STL algorithms

Tags: c++, c++20

I have an algorithm which generates combinations from entries of a container and I want to find the combination which minimizes a cost function:

```
struct Vec { double x; double y; };

double cost( Vec a, Vec b ) {
    double dx = a.x - b.x; 
    double dy = a.y - b.y; 
    return dx*dx + dy*dy;
}


pair<Vec,Vec> get_pair_with_minimum_cost ( vector<Vec> inp, double (*cost_fun)(Vec,Vec) )
{
    pair<Vec,Vec> result;
    double min_cost = FLT_MAX;

    size_t sz = inp.size();
    for(size_t i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        for (size_t j=i; j<sz; j++) {
            double cost = cost_fun(inp[i], inp[j]);
            if (cost < min_cost) {
                min_cost = cost;
                result = make_pair(inp[i], inp[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

vector <Vec> inp = {....};

auto best_pair = get_pair_with_minimum_cost ( inp, cost );
```

Unfortunately, `get_pair_with_minimum_cost()` does 2 jobs:

- generates the combinations
- gets the minimum element

I could break them in two functions, like:

- the generator:

  ```
  template <class Func>
  void generate_all_combinations_of( vector<Vec> inp, Func fun )
  {
      size_t sz = inp.size();
      for(size_t i=0; i<sz; i++) {
          for (size_t j=i; j<sz; j++) {
              fun(make_pair(inp[i], inp[j]));
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- and then use `std::min_element` on the output of the generator, i.e.

  ```
  vector<Vec> inp = {....};
  vector<pair<Vec,Vec>> all_combinations;
  generate_all_combinations_of(inp, [&](vector<pair<Vec,Vec>> o){all_combinations.push_back(o); } );
  auto best_pair = *min_element(all_combinations.begin(), all_combinations.end(), cost);
  ```

but I do not want the pay the cost of creating and extra container with temporary data (`all_combinations`).

### Questions:

1. Can I rewrite the `generate_all_combinations_of()` such that it uses `yield` or the new `std::ranges` in such a way that I can combine it with STL algorithms such as `find_if`, `any_of`, `min_element` or even `adjacent_pair` ?
   The great thing about this 'generator' function is that it is easy to read, so I would like to keep it as readable as possible.
   **NB:** some of these algorithms need to `break` the loop.
2. What is the official name of combining entries this way?
   It this the combinations used in 'bubble-sort'.

Comment: You're looking for [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). More specifically k-combinations (where k=2, so most specifically 2-combinations). You're actually looking at combinations of _indices_, since there's no guarantee each element is unique.

Comment: Do you want to return the indices of the pair with the minimum cost, or just the value of the minimum cost? Also, if you are considering pairs of the same elements (i.e. `j == i`), the answer is trivially 0. Is `cost` supposed to be any arbitrary symmetric function?

Comment: @cigien, the 'cost' was not the or what the combinations are is not really my concern. What I am really looking for is how to "connect" a function which generates values so that it can work with stl algorithms, which expect iterators!

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Just confirming what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've posted a solution that solves this particular problem. It's not a general `generator` solution, but it should give you ideas for how to achieve something similar with comparable efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2168r0.pdf who's development I would follow

If you are using MSVC, and can use their experimental/generator (not sure if others support it yet), you can use

```cpp
std::experimental::generator<std::size_t> Generate(std::size_t const end){
   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < end; ++i)
      co_yield i;
}

int main(){
   auto vals = Generate(22);
   auto const result = *std::min_element(std::begin(vals),std::end(vals));
   std::cout <<'\n' << " " << result;
}
```

Here you would need to modify the Generate function to Yield a pair/or to yield cost

(My recommendation would be to Keep things simple and yield the cost)

Then use vals to find min_cost

## Ranges

Based on what I can find about the Ranges Proposal, it works on the basis of std::begin and std::end both of which `experimental::generator` provides

So it should probably work

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would write the function in c++20, using range views and algorithms so that there isn't a separate container that stores the intermediate results:

```
double get_minimum_cost(auto const & inp)
{
  namespace rs = std::ranges;
  namespace rv = std::ranges::views;

  // for each i compute the minimum cost for all j's  
  auto min_cost_from_i = [&](auto i) 
  {

    auto costs_from_i = rv::iota(i + 1, inp.size())
                      | rv::transform([&](auto j) 
                        { 
                          return cost(inp[i], inp[j]); 
                        });

    return *rs::min_element(costs_from_i);
  };

  // compute min costs for all i's
  auto all_costs = rv::iota(0u, inp.size())
                 | rv::transform(min_cost_from_i);

  return *rs::min_element(all_costs);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n84bzf).

Note that the solution doesn't compare the cost between same elements, since the `cost` function example you showed would have a trivial result of 0. For a cost function that doesn't return 0, you can adapt the solution to generate a range from `i` instead of `i + 1`. Also, if the `cost` function is not symmetric, make that range start from 0 instead of `i`.

Also, this function has UB if you call it with an empty range, so you should check for that as well.

Comment: I think your answer demonstrates that std:ranges can indeed solve such problems. However, it appears that this sort of problems would be solved more readably with coroutines.

Comment: @GrimFandango Readability is subjective, but yes, one version might be more readable than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write the function in c++17, using algorithms' min_element function, with no need for a separate container that stores the intermediate results.  I know you were looking for a c++20 solution, but this code does work fine under c++20, and perhaps it gives you some ideas about adapting functions to ranges when the range isn't just one of the ranges supplied by c++20's ranges library.

```
// TwoContainerRanger is an iterable container where the iterator consists
// of two indices that match the given filter, and whose iterators, when
// dereferenced, return the result of calling func with the
// elements of the two containers, at those two indices.
// filter can be nullptr.
template <typename Container1, typename Container2, typename Func>
struct TwoContainerRanger {
  Container1 &c1;
  Container2 &c2;
  const Func &fun;
  bool (*restriction)(size_t i1, size_t i2);

  TwoContainerRanger(Container1 &container1, Container2 &container2,
                     bool (*filter)(size_t i1, size_t i2), const Func &func)
      : c1(container1), c2(container2), fun(func), restriction(filter) {}

  struct Iterator {
    const TwoContainerRanger *gen;
    size_t index1, index2;
    auto &operator++() {
      do {
        if (++index1 == gen->c1.size()) {
          if (++index2 == gen->c2.size()) {
            // we leave both indices pointing to the end
            // to indicate that we have reached the end.
            return *this;
          } else {
            index1 = 0u;
          }
        }
      } while (gen->restriction && gen->restriction(index1, index2) == false);
      return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const Iterator &other) const = default;
    bool operator!=(const Iterator &other) const = default;
    auto operator*() const {
      return gen->fun(gen->c1[index1], gen->c2[index2]);
    }
  };
  Iterator begin() {
    Iterator b{this, size_t(0) - 1, 0u};
    return ++b;  // automatically applies the restriction
  }
  Iterator end() { return Iterator{this, c1.size(), c2.size()}; }
};
```

Calling it looks like this:

```
int main() {
  std::array<Vec, 5> ar = {Vec{0, 0}, Vec{1, 1}, Vec{3, 3}, Vec{7, 7},
                           Vec{3.1, 3.1}};
  TwoContainerRanger tcr{ar, ar, Triangle, cost};

  auto result = std::min_element(tcr.begin(), tcr.end());
  std::cout << "Min was at (" << result.index1 << "," << result.index2
            << "); cost was " << *result << '\n';
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d74M6c).

Comment: I appreciate this solution also. I think the big challenge when writing iterators like that is keeping the logic clean, contained in one place, and revealing its intention.